# How to add TapGestureRecognizer to outer StackLayout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I have two nested StackLayouts:

```
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I would like to add click event on outer StackLayout that will not be triggered when inner StackLayout is clicked. Is it possible in Xamarin Forms? If I can filter click event (with if block) I would also be happy.

Comment: are you sure you can add a TapGesture to a StackLayout? I think you can only add TGR only to Controls, not to Layouts

Comment: Yes. You can put <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers><TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" />               </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

Comment: ok but what are trying to do with a TGR added to a StackLayout? why you should tap the StackLayout? You should tap a contro... sorry but I don't understand what are you doing

Comment: I have two nested StackLayouts. When I click outer one, I would like event to be triggered. When I click inner one, I would like not to be triggered. Similar behavior is with DisplayAlert: when you click out of it - it is closed; when you click on alert, it is not closed; when you click "ok" - it is also closed. That is exactly what I need. I need modal that will show content that is clickable and I would like modal to autoclose when it is clicked out of inner StackLayout.

Comment: Is there Modal implementation that could be used in similar way as DisplayAlert, but where content could be set? I would like to put clickable list as content and I would also like to close it - when it is clicked out of modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can take a look to [Rg Plugin popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).

it has this property

**CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked: Close pop-up when click on the background**

```
You can add what you want to this popup because you can add a ContentPage

// Use these methods in PopupNavigation globally or Navigation in your pages

// Open new PopupPage
Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync

// Hide last PopupPage
Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync

// Hide all PopupPage with animations
Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync

// Remove one popup page in stack
Task RemovePageAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync
```